# Why moderator does not undelete that answer?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

I surprised, when I saw [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485549/6935629) that have a number of upvoted. 
I have added snapshot of that answer because below 10k reputation users does not see deleted posts.

[image: deleted_post]

So, I have a questions:

- Why moderator does not undelete that answer?
- Are many other users, forcing to delete that answer?
- Is it possible to undelete that?

Comment: We are not the owner, and we can't read minds. No, we'll not undelete it.

Comment: Sometimes upvoted answers may have unseen issues.. There is even a [disciplined badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) for deleting one's own upvoted answer..

Comment: Why do you think a moderator should undelete it? You did not explain that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because, as people are discussing in the comments, the code in the answer is flawed. OP decided to delete it, despite its popularity, to prevent any further spreading of the incorrect information.

Comment: Thus why we have the Disciplined badge.

Comment: I would say that we aren't deleting enough popular but flawed answers/questions.